# Angular route does not navigate to route until data is resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a simple web app that has a detail page. When end users click on the link the route does navigate to the page until the data on the page is ready. Ideally I would like to display the page right away and update the UI accordingly. Is there anything I am doing incorrectly? Below please review what I have.

**In my routes file:**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';

export const AppRoutes:Routes = [
 { path: 'details/:id', component: DetailsComponent },
 { path: '', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

**View from where link is clicked to navigate to details**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of privateInfo; let i = index">
      <span>{{i}}</span>
      <span><a [routerLink]="['/details', i]">Review Details</a></span>
</div>
```

**Detail Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PrivateModel } from '../models/app-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  template: `
    <div>
     <pre>{{ privateInfo }}</pre>
    </div>
  `
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
public privateInfo:Array<any>;
public detailID;

constructor(public PrivateModel:PrivateModel, private    route:ActivatedRoute) {
  this.detailID = route.snapshot.params['id'];
}

ngOnInit() {
  this. privateInfo = this.PrivateModel[this.detailID];
}
}
```

Looking at the Angular docs there seems to be a [noPreloading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NoPreloading-class.html) class but not sure how to utilize that. Any help and or an extra set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the resolve property during your route definition as below,

```
export const AppRoutes:Routes = [
     { path: 'details/:id', component: DetailsComponent ,resolve: {details: DetailsResolver} },
     { path: '', redirectTo:'/import', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

Your DetailsResolver service must be as below

```
import { Injectable }             from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailsService } from '....';
@Injectable()
export class DetailResolver implements Resolve<Details> {
  constructor(private cs: DetailsService, private router: Router) {}
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Details> {
    let id = route.params['id'];
    return this.cs.getDetails(id).then(details => {
      if (details) {
        return details;
      } else { // id not found
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```